# How to Download Files From 115.com?

Tags: security, web, download

I am trying to download a file from 115.com , I have created a login credentials on their webites , but still I am not able to download file from that website.

The project I am downloading is mentioned in this link :
http://115.com/file/e74944rn#cocos2dSpaceGameDemo.zip

I googgled alot, go through certain blogs but still not able to download that file. Please suggest an approach to download this file.

Regards,
Pardeep sharma

Comment: Sorry but how is this related to programming?

Comment: To program you need an example , and I am trying to download that example. But this chinese website is really messed up!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

click 存至网盘 (1st button) to copy the file to your own 115.com account. click top left 网盘 logo to return to homepage. download accordingly for free from your file directory.

the 离线下载 (orange button) allows for direct downloading but is a paid vip service.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick step-by-step guide:

[image]

(Got it from here: http://hostmypicture.com/images/115downloa.png.)

Comment: You should add that picture here instead of only like it.

Comment: Late reply.
A reputation of at least ten is required, is it not?

Comment: Not sure, maybe.  I fixed your post.